# How to get the position of a SpotLight in three js?

Tags: three.js

I have two `SpotLights` in my canvas. One is front side and the other is left side. I know how to set them but I want to know how I can get the exact position. Maybe using console.log?

```
 itsLight.position.set(?,?,?);
```

Comment: `THREE.Object3D.getWorldPosition();` Documentation: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.getWorldPosition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light's position is in the `position` attribute:

```
console.log(itsLight.position.x, itsLight.position.y, itsLight.position.z);
```

The coordinates for front side and left side depend on where you have your camera. It also depends on what kind of light it is. DirectionalLight and PointLight behave differently.